# Split a string into a list with parts of N characters in reversed order

Tags: python, string

I have a string of a fixed length.

```
>>> s = "000000000001048700000010768"
```

I need to split this string into parts of 5 characters in reversed order (starting from last character).
The output should be:

> 00 00000 00001 04870 00000 10768

I found the `textwrap` module, which does the splitting, But the output is slightly different.

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> print ' '.join(textwrap.wrap(s, 5))
00000 00000 01048 70000 00107 68
```

Is there an easy solution to do this that I am missing? Maybe to use `s.format()`

Comment: Do you want to split it or do you want to insert spaces? Not clear.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I just need to add spaces. My approach was to split it and join it in a second step. Is there a way to do this without splitting?

Comment: I recommend http://xyproblem.info then.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the string before you split it.

```
parts = textwrap.wrap(s[::-1], 5)
```

Then you can reverse the list, to go back to the original order.

```
print " ".join(parts[::-1])
```

Or in short:

```
print " ".join(textwrap.wrap(s[::-1], 5)[::-1])
```

Comment: I don't think the string needs ot be reversed (see example output), I think the OP just means 'the grouping should run right-to-left'

Comment: @TomDalton I fixed the answer, I think it fits to what to OP wants.

Comment: Thanks @TomDalton for clarifying. This is what i  meant to say.

Comment: @Neo Thanks for your answer. This fixes my problem. PS: Your Answer is missing a space character.

Comment: Single reverse of the whole result is enough: `" ".join(parts)[::-1]`

Comment: So the whole thing could just be `" ".join(textwrap.wrap(s[::-1], 5))[::-1]`

Comment: @Neo Well, it wasn't wrong, just unnecessarily complicated. *Now* it's wrong, because you're reversing the list instead of the join result as I suggested. Check the output.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without textwrap and reversing the string twice:

```
print ' '.join(s[max(i-5, 0):i] for i in reversed(range(len(s), 0, -5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex way, now that you confirmed that you don't actually want to split but just add spaces.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('(.{5})(?=.)', r'\1 ', s[::-1])[::-1]
'00 00000 00001 04870 00000 10768'
```

This grabs five chars followed by something (I wish `\z` would work) and replaces them with themselves plus a space. Reversing the input string beforehand and the output string afterwards in order to do the right-to-left grouping.